# VSCode on Ubuntu 20.04 - black screen issue

Tags: visual-studio-code, ubuntu-20.04, launch

[Image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Md4cK.png)
As seen in the picture VSCode upon launching is not working, there is blank screen displayed and trying to e.g. a new terminal only shows one more black box in the terminal's place. No extensions whatsoever were installed lately.

Solutions found under some other posts (although not completely describing my problem), including restarting the program, computer, reinstalling VSCode didn't help to solve the issue.

Comment: check for updates in VSC. mine updated today.

 Version: 1.82.2 (user setup)
Commit: abd2f3db4bdb28f9e95536dfa84d8479f1eb312d
Date: 2023-09-14T05:55:25.390Z
Electron: 25.8.1
ElectronBuildId: 23779380
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22621

Answer (score 9):

Try this solution, it worked for me:

```
cd $HOME/.config/Code
rm -r GPUCache
```

Source: https://medium.com/@syafiqza/blank-screen-in-visual-studio-code-d84707001c94

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I can assure that it works for me

Comment: Worked for me too

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue on Ubuntu 20.04.
You can open VScode by typing:

```
code --disable-gpu
```

In order to disable the hardware acceleration in vscode:

Click: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd>

Type:
`Preferences: Configure Runtime Arguments`

Uncomment the following:
`"disable-hardware-acceleration": true`

Restart VScode.